# How to deserialize Firestore DocumentSnapshot containing DocumentReference using Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, deserialization, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following Firestore structure :

[image: Firestore : User collection]

I manage to deserialize it using Kotlin but only using `Any` as type for city and activities. So far this is my data class :

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class User (
        var firstName: String,
        var lastName: String,
        var displayName: String,
        var birthday: Date,
        var memberSince: Date,
        var city: Any,
        var activities: ArrayList<Any>
) {
    constructor():this("", "", "", Date(), Date(), Any(), ArrayList(0))
}
```

And here is how i retrieve the data and deserialize :

```
DocumentReference userRef = mFirestoreDB.collection("user").document(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
userRef.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
            final User user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
            Log.i(TAG, user.toString());
        } else if(e != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving user data from Firestore", e);
        }
    }
});
```

I was wondering, is there i way i can strongly type city and activities to be `DocumentReference` as it should ?

Comment: What serialization library are you using? or, does the Firebase library do serialization?

Comment: Firebase provides a [toObject(java.lang.Class<T>)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#toObject(java.lang.Class<T>)) method to deserialize. I added some code of how i do the deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i found how to do this. So all you need to do is to use this awsome declaration : [lateinit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) which as the doc says :

> Normally, properties declared as having a non-null type must be
>   initialized in the constructor. However, fairly often this is not
>   convenient. For example, properties can be initialized through
>   dependency injection, or in the setup method of a unit test. In this
>   case, you cannot supply a non-null initializer in the constructor, but
>   you still want to avoid null checks when referencing the property
>   inside the body of a class.

My data class looks now like :

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class User2 (
        var firstName: String,
        var lastName: String,
        var displayName: String,
        var birthday: Date,
        var memberSince: Date,
        var activities: ArrayList<DocumentReference>
) {
    lateinit var city: DocumentReference
    constructor():this("", "", "", Date(), Date(), ArrayList(0))
}
```

Note to self : I really need to read more about Kotlin...